# How can I print output of ps command with its column name?

Tags: rhel, ps

In the CLI of RHEL 7.6, ps command shows many columns of output.
I can guess meanings of some of them but do know all of them.
Can I show the results of ps command with its column name?

Comment: Are you asking for what the columns mean? Check the section "STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS" in the `ps` manual on your Linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply show the columns name first, then run your command after that.

```bsh
$ ps | head -n1; ps | grep localhost

PID TTY           TIME CMD
14270 ttys001    0:00.04 ssh example@localhost
```

EDIT:
A *cleaner* solution (suggested by [@Jeremy-Boden](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/205853/jeremy-boden)):

```bsh
$ ps | grep -E 'localhost|PID'
```

Comment: `ps | grep -E 'localhost|PID'` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

The headers of the columns for ps are the first thing that get printed out when running the command. If you are just looking to see what the headers are, then you could do something simple like piping ps into head to take a look. Something like this `ps | head -n1` will only show you the headers of the columns.

If you are looking to be able to see the headers within your ps output, which may be lengthy then you could pipe your `ps` command into `awk`.

There may be a smarter way to handle this in `awk` (or just in general), but here is what I would do...I'll use `ps -ef` as my ps example, but I think it will work for anything.

`ps -ef | awk '{if(NR==1){HEADER=$0} if(NR%10 == 1){print "\n"HEADER}{print $0}}'`

The awk statement is first checking if it is at the first line, and if so setting a variable to the value of that line, which I call `HEADER`: `if(NR==1){HEADER=$0}`

But you probably only want to print the header every so often, so the next part is checking if the record number (in this case line) is divisible by 10 and if it is, printing a new line (to break it up and make it readable) and the header line. You can change 10 to a lower number to have the headers printed more often, or a larger number to have them printed less often: `if(NR%10 ==1){print "\n"HEADER}`

The last part of the awk statement is then just printing the line that awk is at, which is just the regular output from `ps`: `{print $0}`.